# C# How to duplicate line in text file (.txt) when button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, duplicates, workflow-foundation

I've a winform application and I want to ducplicate a line in a text file (.txt) when I click a button.
eg :
Hello world

and I want to have something like:

Hello world

Hello world

when I click a button.

```
void duplicateLine(string text, int line){
//Read text file
//duplicate the line
//insert (Write) the duplicate line in text file(.txt)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to duplicate a line in a text file in C# is to use the **File.ReadAllLines** method to read the file into a string array, then use a loop to insert the duplicate line at the desired index, and then use the **File.WriteAllLines** method to write the modified array back to the file. For example, the following code snippet duplicates the first line of a text file:

```
void duplicateLine(string text, int line)
{
    //Read the file into a string array
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("textfile.txt");
    
    //Create a list to store the modified lines
    List<string> newLines = new List<string>();
    
    //Loop through the array and insert the duplicate line
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        //Add the original line to the list
        newLines.Add(lines[i]);
    
        //If the line is the one to be duplicated, add it again
        if (i == line)
        {
            newLines.Add(lines[i]);
        }
    }
    
    //Write the modified list back to the file
    File.WriteAllLines("textfile.txt", newLines);
}
```

This code will result in a text file like this:

```
Hello world
Hello world
Some other line
Another line
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explication, I just want to duplicate one line when I click a button.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write the code yourself and ask questions about the code problems. Try the following method:

1-Read all line of file to list using `File.ReadAllLines`

2- check line if not exist in the file

3-Add a new line at a specific position of list( duplicate one line)

4-Write list to file

```
void duplicateLine(string text, int line){

    string _path = "data.txt";  //path of your file
    var txtLines = File.ReadAllLines(_path).ToList();  //1 

    if(line>=txtLines.Count) //2
    {
        MessageBox.Show("this line not exist in file..");
        return;
    }
    txtLines.Insert(line, Text);  //3
    File.WriteAllLines(_path, txtLines); //4
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the duplicateLine function solved my question.